# $a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2^n} f(\frac{k}{2^n})$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\ \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function, and 
the sequence $(a_n)$ is defined as follows:
$$a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} f\left(\dfrac{k}{2^n}\right).$$

Prove that $(a_n)$ is convergent.

I am not even sure how to begin. can someone please help me?

Comment: I think you should write out the first few terms and compare them from one to the next to get an idea for what this is doing exactly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a subsequence of the Riemann sum

$$a_m = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^m f\left(\frac{k}{m}\right) \to \int_0^1 f(x)\:dx$$

If the limit exists then all subsequential limits will converge to the same thing. Now, is convexity enough to show that the function is Riemann integrable?